# Ask a terminology for a $C^1$ and one-to-one function with nonzero Jacobian everywhere.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, differential-geometry, terminology

Let $U\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ open, $f:U\to\Bbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ function, and $\forall x\in U,~\det\mathbf{D}f(x)\neq 0$ and $f$ is one-to-one. Such function have many good properties in analysis. But what is it called? I have read a japanese book called it "regular function", but I feel that "regular" may have overlap with others things in mathematics. Fitzpatrick's *Advanced Calculus* called it "smooth change of variables". And those are the only two resource I have that a name is given. Is there other names, official or custom, for such functions?

PS: I haven't studied neither topology nor differential geometry. Maybe there's a standard name in these field?

Comment: It seems to me like you're looking for "embedding", but I might have some minor detail wrong.

Comment: I'd say "a $C^1$-embedding" or "a $C^1$-diffeomorphism to its image".

Comment: @MoisheCohen But is $C^1$-diffeomorphism necessarily $\det\mathbf{D}f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$?

Comment: @Eric: yes, just use the fact that a square matrix is invertible if and only if it has nonzero determinant.